# Asynchronous Listening on class that launched asynchronous process

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, listener

SOLVED VERSION

Ok so here it is. I am not even sure how to properly ask the question. I am creating a form that pops up within a program asynchronously so that it doesn't interfere with the main program. Within this form, I want to display data that comes from the "base class", in this example, it's the Metronome class. The Metronome class is also the same class that launched the form asynchronously.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this or if this is even possible. I have looked at various tutorials and can't seem to get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace Project2
{
    public class TimeOfTick : EventArgs
    {
        private DateTime TimeNow;
        public DateTime Time
        {
            set
            {
                TimeNow = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return this.TimeNow;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Metronome
    {
        public event TickHandler Tick;
        public delegate void TickHandler(Metronome m, TimeOfTick e);

        public delegate void ListenerDelegate();
        public static void myCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            ListenerDelegate del = (ListenerDelegate)result.AsyncState;
            del.EndInvoke(result);
        }

        public void MetronomeStarter()
        {
            Listener listen = new Listener();
            listen.MetronomeItem = this;
            ListenerDelegate del = new ListenerDelegate(listen.Starter);
            del.BeginInvoke(myCallback, del);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                if (Tick != null)
                {
                    TimeOfTick TOT = new TimeOfTick();
                    TOT.Time = DateTime.Now;
                    Tick(this, TOT);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Listener
    {
        private Metronome metronomeItem;   
        public Metronome MetronomeItem
        {
            get { return metronomeItem; }
            set { metronomeItem = value; }
        }

        public void Starter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Listener class");           
            metronomeItem.Tick += new Metronome.TickHandler(HeardIt);            
        }

        void HeardIt(Metronome m, TimeOfTick e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("HEARD IT AT {0}", e.Time);
        }

    }

    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Metronome m = new Metronome();            
            m.MetronomeStarter();
            m.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a public Metronome property within your Listener class, and set that property to "this" in your MetronomeStarter method.  That will give you full access in the Listener class to everything in the Metronome object that instantiated the Listener object.

```
 public void MetronomeStarter() 
        { 
            Listener listen = new Listener(); 
            listen.MetronomeItem = this;
            ListenerDelegate del = new ListenerDelegate(listen.Starter); 
            del.BeginInvoke(myCallback, del); 
        }
```

Comment: How exactly do you do that?? I am a pretty new to C# and I didn't quite get what you said. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: And what about the Metronome property? :-) Is that the get/set type of thing?

Comment: In your listener class, change the "m" field to a property: if you name it MetronomeItem instead of "m", make it public with a get and set, the code will work the way you want it--based on the sample I provided..

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you again but this doesn't seem to be working. I edited the code in my initial post. What am I doing wrong? 

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ok nevermind I am officially an idiot. I got it now. Just had to remove the new Metronome part. My bad. Thanks for your help Russ.